# Mesibo message list title shows the number but i want user name

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mesibo

Currently I am using  mesibo  open source lib for one to one chat and voice and video calling.
I am  using 2 approaches to open message list
first one : using Fragment list

```
MesiboUserListFragment userListFragment = new MesiboUserListFragment();
userListFragment.setListener(this);
Bundle bl = new Bundle();
bl.putInt(MesiboUserListFragment.MESSAGE_LIST_MODE, MesiboUserListFragment.MODE_MESSAGELIST);
userListFragment.setArguments(bl);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.userlist_fragment, userListFragment, "null");
ft.commit();
```

second way :

```
int flag = 0;
boolean startInBackground = false;
boolean keepRunningOnBackPressed = false;
MesiboUI.launch(this, flag, startInBackground, keepRunningOnBackPressed);
```

But every time open in  message list some user title shows its mobile number and some user title there name.
I want to show only user name not its mobile number.
Help us thanks in adavnce. sorry for my english

Comment: You will not get any support from Mesibo. I spent several months with this company and then gave up. If you post questions, comments on Github, they just delete them and block you.

Comment: then what to do bro. becuse I am stuck in problem.